# Joint pdf of X and Y with absolute value

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, self-learning, absolute-value

Question.

Joint probability function of continuous probability X, Y is here :

$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = k(|x|-|y|) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (-1< y< x< 2)$

Then what is k?

I mean how can I differentiate absolute value range??

Please help me with a solution.

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference)  to formulate your question.

Answer (score 2):

Joint pdf integrates out to 1, so you should have
$$
1 = \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} f_{X,Y} (x,y) dxdy
$$
Substituting you get
$$
1 = k \int_{-1}^2 \int_{-1}^x (|x| - |y|) dydx
$$
can you finish this?

Comment: Thank you for your kindness that correct my false input.

I'm really sorry, I questioned this step and its after. I experienced some definite integrals with absolute value but, in this case I really don't know how I set range.

Comment: I'm really poor at English.. Sorry